# Windows 7 breaks appearance inside office documents (word, excel)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I scroll the excel sheet, sometimes the ribbon and even the top bar are being covered by cells. The visualization is being broken. The same thing occurs with MS Word, too. The problem occurs even during typing. This is very annoying and occurs very often. When I minimize/maximize, everything is being recovered, but unfortunately it remains only for a short time. These pictures are an example of the situation.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TZpGL8zoVwTTBzdTZIOEhMMlU/view?pli=1

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TZpGL8zoVwOHBWaG83U1hyWVk/view?pli=1

**EDIT**: I use office 2010

Comment: Pls mention the version of Office suite. If it's office 2013, check out MS-KB article. Performance and display issues in Office 2013 client applications : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768648 (check out the 2nd symptom mentioned)

Comment: I use office 2010

Comment: The KB article above should apply to Office 2010 as well. (Disabling Hardware Acceleration)

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration didn't help. I downloaded and installed  OffCAT.msi tool, then scanned, it recommended an update (kb2956191), I downloaded and installed the update, but it also couldn't help. I think this is much more Windows related issue, but I can't figure it out.